# How to find out file name through int-descriptor? (or "can I..?")

Tags: c++, file-io

I open file in this way:

```
errno_t err01;   
int fHandle;
err01 = _sopen_s(&fHandle, fileName, _O_RDWR, _SH_DENYRW, 0);
```

Now I should use the int-descriptor (named `fHandle` in this example) as identificator of the file.

**Question**: can I, knowing only this int-descriptor, get the file name, which corresponds to it? (suppose, I have lost value of `fileName` variable after opening the file)

Comment: if possible, it will most probably be OS-dependent. Btw. so, is that linux or windows? On windows, ProcessHacker seems to be able to find the paths for each handle found in the process' list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the file handle like this:

```
HANDLE hFile;
int fHandle;
err01 = _sopen_s(&fHandle, "blah.txt", _O_RDWR, _SH_DENYRW, 0);
hFile = (HANDLE) _get_osfhandle(fHandle);
```

Then just use functions that work with a file HANDLE, for example

```
GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hFile, Path, BUFSIZE, VOLUME_NAME_NT);
_tprintf(TEXT("path is %s\n"), Path);
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks! It works. But if I want to get only file name (not whole path), can I get it? or I only must to extract it from a path-string? (I searched [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232(v=vs.85).aspx), but didn't find any appropriate function)

Comment: This is a bit of a long winded way:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx